# Как сделать 2 блока на одной строчке и расположить их на ней по разные стороны, т.е. одни слева, другой справа

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть 2 блока в одном. Они должны быть:
1) Располагаться в одной строчке
2) Быть по разные стороны[image: одни блок слева, другой справа]

Comment: [Игрушка для освоения flex](http://flexboxfroggy.com/). Я таких несколько видел, полезно пройти какую-нибудь одну)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container div {
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Задать float-ы для дочерних блоков.
И clear для родителя.

```css
div1 {
  float: left;
}
div2 {
  float: right;
}

main-div:after {
  content:'';
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.container div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
   float:left;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```